# property of complementary cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability

$$\Bbb{E}(X) = \int_0^\infty xf(x)dx \ge \int_0^c xf(x)dx + c \int_c^\infty f(x)dx$$

I'm having trouble understanding the above formula.

I do understand that $ \Bbb{E}(X) = \int_0^\infty xf(x)dx \ge \int_0^c xf(x)dx$ but I don't yet get where $c \int_c^\infty f(x)dx$ comes from , how it relates to it all..

Please explain in mathnoob-friendly terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $c>0$ 
$$
\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^cxf(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_c^\infty xf(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
and 
$$
\int_c^\infty xf(x)\,\mathrm dx\geq \int_c^\infty cf(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
since $0\leq cf(x)\leq xf(x)$ for all $x\in [c,\infty)$.

Comment: wow, epiphany. thanks guys!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

We have by aditivity of the integral in the domain, that
$$ \int_0^\infty xf(x)\, dx = \int_0^c xf(x)\, dx + \int_c^\infty xf(x)\, dx $$
Now, look at the second integral: For each $x \in [c,\infty)$, we have as $f(x) \ge 0$ ($f$ being a pdf) that $xf(x) \ge cf(x)$. Integrating this over $[c,\infty)$ gives
$$ \int_c^\infty xf(x)\, dx \ge \int_c^\infty cf(x)\, dx = c\int_c^\infty f(x)\, dx. $$
So, alltogether
$$ \int_0^\infty xf(x)\, dx \ge \int_0^c xf(x)\, dx + c\int_c^\infty f(x)\, dx $$
as wanted.